# Looking for a flexible alternative to the standard VB Msg Box

Tags: windows, vb6

I'm looking for a flexible alternative to the standard Windows (VB) message box for us in VB6.

I'd like features such as:
1. Non-modal (but always on top)
2. Timer (so that it disappears after X seconds)
3. Custom button names. (Instead of saying "do you want to quit? Click Yes" I can have "Quit" and "Continue" on the button names.

I've found a few options, which I'll list as answers.

Comment: Why not create your own form and show it modally?

Comment: There are a lot of other features I'd like (see below) and I thought "hey, why reinvent the wheel".

Comment: I was going to suggest making your own as well. It's been many years since I've had to work with vb6, but I remember I DID make my own. Start with a dialogbox and go. Use parameters to set your features. Once you do it you'll feel a sense of freedom. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From Source-Code planet:

**Extension of the standard Msg Box**
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=58808&lngWId=1
*API replacement function for the native MsgBox function - or as I like to call it - "what is the upper limits of parameters to a function ?" Allows centering over forms. 09/24 - Added ability to timeout the message box. 09/26 - Added the ability to add custom icons. 09/26 - Added countdown message and ability to change button text.*
+ Easy to use 
+ very similar to standard msgbox (looks like it just has some api calls to extend the features)
+ Custom button names
- doesn't have a non-modal option

Also from SCP:
**Complete replacement for the Message Box**

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=63332&lngWId=1
+very feature rich (includes everything I wanted) 
-Very difficult to use. (about 15 parameters with no use of Enums so you have to read the documentation every time you try to use it: intellisense provides not guidance.

Comment: write your own enums then! They are treated as a zero based range of integers